# 4 percentage input boxes , how to adjust values dinamically up to 100%

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show the user four input boxes, starting with 25% each of them. If the user changes any of the values in a input box the value displayed in the three others will calculate accordingly. Example :let's say that a user choose to change one of theme to 20% I expect the others to be 26.6

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide what you've tried to accomplish the task?

Comment: So far i manage to get the sum of all of the values

Comment: function getSum(total, num) {
          return total + num;
        }

        if ($scope.priorityPercentages.reduce(getSum) > 100)
            return true;

Comment: You'll have to do something like `100 - [value of input that was changed] / [number of remaining inputs]` to get the value you want to set the other inputs to. Then it's a simple matter of updating the model behind those inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get all the elements then add a class on `focus` remove it on `blur`. This class will be used to target rest of the element and update their value

```js
//get all the input with specified name and add event lister to it
[...document.getElementsByName('userInp')].forEach(function(item) {
  // on focusing adding a class to the current target
  item.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('focus')

  });
  // removing the class on blurring from current target
  item.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('focus')

  });
  item.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    // get the value from the target input
    let getVal = e.target.value;
    if (getVal < 100) {
      // devide equally among rest of the inputs for this example it is 3
      let eachVal = (100 - getVal) / 3
      // then select all the input which does not have class focus
      // and update their value
      document.querySelectorAll("input:not(.focus)").forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.value = eachVal.toFixed(2)
      })

    }


  })
})
```

```html
<input type='text' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='text' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='text' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='text' name='userInp' value='25'>
```

Comment: Very interesting usage of the first spread operator to avoid using `.call`.

Comment: @briosheje `Array.from` is another option

Comment: Amazing, this is extacly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: How could I actually type something like 20% 20% 20 % 40% , since all the values are updated al the time and the division is always by 3 it seems to create some issues

Comment: @AutDev could not get the requirement. Can you please create a demo and show

Comment: The total sum of the percentages should be 100% . The user might type 20%,20%,20% on the first three options and the last one should be filled automatically to 40% . Another example could be 10% 15% 20% and the last one should be filled with 55%. In case the user types 40%,40%,20% , the last input would be filled with 0%

Answer (score 0):

While brk's answer shows a way to manage setting all other fields to an *equally shared* value, it is probably no what most people want. The following will change the other fields according to their *relative ratio to each other*.

### Note: Special case if one item is 100%

Please note that the following solution does not handle the special case where one item takes it all (100%) and *all* other items are 0% and then the 100% item is reduced by any amount. In this case the new remaining value (`100% - new value`) could be split equally among the other items. But because this might be use case dependent, I leave this as an easy exercise to integrate.

## Text fields

```js
var isRunning = false;
//get all the input with specified name and add event lister to it
[...document.getElementsByName('userInp')].forEach(function(item) {
if (!isRunning) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function(element) {
    // get the value from the target input
    const getVal = parseFloat(element.target.value);
    if (getVal <= 100) {
      isRunning = true;
      // devide among rest while keeping their relative ratio
      const otherFields = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("userInp")).filter(e => e != item);
      const change = 100 - otherFields.map(e => parseFloat(e.value)).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr) - getVal;
      const oldRest = 100 - (getVal + change);
      otherFields.forEach(function(elem) {
        const old = parseFloat(elem.value);
        elem.value = Math.floor((old + ((old / oldRest) * change)) * 100) / 100;
      })
      isRunning = false;
    }
  })
}
  })
```

```html
<input type='number' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='number' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='number' name='userInp' value='25'>
<input type='number' name='userInp' value='25'>
```

## Sliders

Here is the same with sliders for better visualization:

```js
var isRunning = false;
//get all the input with specified name and add event lister to it
[...document.getElementsByName('userInp')].forEach(function(item) {
if (!isRunning) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function(element) {
    // get the value from the target input
    const getVal = parseFloat(element.target.value);
    if (getVal <= 100) {
      isRunning = true;
      // devide among rest while keeping their relative ratio
      const otherFields = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("userInp")).filter(e => e != item);
      const change = 100 - otherFields.map(e => parseFloat(e.value)).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr) - getVal;
      const oldRest = 100 - (getVal + change);
      otherFields.forEach(function(elem) {
        const old = parseFloat(elem.value);
        elem.value = Math.floor((old + ((old / oldRest) * change)) * 100) / 100;
      })
      isRunning = false;
    }
  })
}
  })
```

```html
<input type='range' name='userInp' value='25' min="0", max="100">
<input type='range' name='userInp' value='25' min="0", max="100">
<input type='range' name='userInp' value='25' min="0", max="100">
<input type='range' name='userInp' value='25' min="0", max="100">
```